# Open graph link showing up in description box?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I am posting an open graph story that contains a photo object onto the users page, just like the Scrumptious Facebook sample project.

The open graph story that gets posted shoes the image, the heading and then where the description should be it posts the open graph url.

Here is the open graph url I use.

https://hidden-castle-7245.herokuapp.com/opengraphobject.php?fb:app_id=554329451276476
&og:type=gopiratestd:boss
&og:title=Charizard
&og:description=%22Whatever%22
&og:image=http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphicmedium/beautiful_cat_picture_6_168770.jpg
&body=Something

and the action is gopiratestd:beat

I using the graph API explorer to post test posts.

Here is an image of the post that appears in the activity log.

[image]

Any way I can fix this?

Also is there anyway of changing what the story links too? When I select the heading or picture in the open graph story it takes me to a blank page that shows the name of the action that was posted. I would like this to link to a separate webpage, is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using double quotes in your `description` parameter, you end up with

```
<meta property="og:description" content=""Whatever"">
```

in your generated HTML, and since that’s invalid, FB’s scraper does not read any description at all from your meta tags.

Drop the quotes around the value, and [the scraper will read your description just fine](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=https://hidden-castle-7245.herokuapp.com/opengraphobject.php?fb%3aapp_id=554329451276476&og%3atype=gopiratestd%3aboss&og%3atitle=Charizard&og%3adescription=Whatever&og%3aimage=http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphicmedium/beautiful_cat_picture_6_168770.jpg&body=Something).

> Also is there anyway of changing what the story links too? When I select the heading or picture in the open graph story it takes me to a blank page that shows the name of the action that was posted.

If you want to output more content on that page – then output more content :-)

> I would like this to link to a separate webpage, is this possible?

The post will always link to the URL that was posted. You can redirect normal users landing on the URL elsewhere if you want, either client-side via JavaScript (that the scraper does not interpret), or server-side (then you have to exclude the scraper from that redirect [via its user agent](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/#scraperinfo)).

Comment: Thank you! I probably never would have spotted those extra quotes. I figured I'd have to get the landing page to redirect for me, was just hoping I missed something in the app settings page. Thanks a mill :)